# Is there a .stamp() method in pygame like in turtle?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a simple pygame project in which you clone yourself by pressing space. I have created this project in Turtle by using `Turtle.stamp()`, but I am not sure if there exists such a thing in pygame.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:

No, there isn't one.

---

Long answer:

However, you can mimic it with ease. Add a list for the "stamps". This list contains the objects ([`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)) and positions where the object has to be drawn:

```py
stamps = []
```

Implement a function `stamp`, that adds images (`pygame.Surface`) and postitions to the list:

```py
def stamp(pos, surf):
    stamps.append((surf, pos))`
```

Add another function that draw the objects onto a target *Surface*:

```py
def draw_stamps(target_surf):
    for pos, surf in stamps:
         target_surf.blit(surf, pos)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

turtle = pygame.Surface((48, 40), pygame.SRCALPHA)
for p in [(5, 5), (27, 5), (5, 35), (27, 35)]:
    pygame.draw.circle(turtle, "brown", p, 5)
pygame.draw.circle(turtle, "green", (40, 20), 8)
pygame.draw.circle(turtle, "darkgreen", (16, 20), 16)
turtle_rect = turtle.get_rect(center = (60, 60))

stamps = []

def stamp(pos, surf):
    stamps.append((pos, surf))

def draw_stamps(target_surf):
    for pos, surf in stamps:
         target_surf.blit(surf, pos)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False  
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            stamp(turtle_rect.topleft, turtle)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    turtle_rect.x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * 5
    turtle_rect.y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * 5 
    turtle_rect.clamp_ip(window.get_rect())              

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    draw_stamps(window)
    window.blit(turtle, turtle_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```